# How SQL Server's "Lock pages in memory" works?

Tags: c++, sql-server

How does **SQL Server** lock pages in memory?

Does it use [VirtualLock](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtuallock)?

Comment: You can check out the latch mechanisim https://www.sqlshack.com/all-about-latches-in-sql-server/

Comment: @ESAT - latches and [Lock Pages in Memory Option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-the-lock-pages-in-memory-option-windows?view=sql-server-ver15) are entirely different topics

Comment: Thanks to @MartinSmith for correcting my misunderstanding.